# Can enums have limited scope if defined inside a struct in c

Tags: c, struct, enums, namespaces, scope

I want to know if an enum can be limited in how it is access by putting it inside a struct. I know that this would work in C++ (that's where I got the idea), but I don't know if it will work in c. So, for example, if I have two different structs

```
struct SaticArrayA
{
    enum { MAX_SIZE = 10 };
    int array[MAX_SIZE];
};
struct SaticArrayB
{
    enum { MAX_SIZE = 20 };
    int array[MAX_SIZE];
};
```

Will this even close to compile? Basically, I want to do what I would do in C++ and give myself a common naming convention across "classes" so that I can ask any array what it's size is, etc.

(p.s. I'm essentially trying to give myself a nicer static array in c that won't lose size information (by decaying to a pointer) the second I try to pass it to another scope).

Comment: The obvious alternative is to adopt a naming convention and have constants named something like `STATIC_ARRAY_A__MAX_SIZE`, in which case I'd probably use a `#define` instead of an `enum`. The question is whether the information can belong to the struct (immutably)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not compile,

you didn't give the enumerator a tag

```
enum { MAX_SIZE = 10 } name ;
```

and you declared two enumerator constants with the same name

```
MAX_SIZE
```

C11 standard on scopes of indentifiers:

> 6.2.1. p7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
>   the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. **Each enumeration constant has scope that
>   begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list.** Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator

This means that your first enumerator has a scope in the entire file from the line it is declared onward.

The second enum declaration with the same name is not correct and should not compile.

It doesn't matter where enums are being declared for this rule, struct or not, once declared they are in file scope from that point on.